# Is there any way to get Active Directory password hash of logged in user?

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, active-directory, ldap

In my WPF application, I want to authenticate on a server in the LAN. Is it possible to get the current user's password/password hash in the WPF applicaion, so I can authenticate with the Windows user name and password without bothering the user about entering the his username and password again in my program?

Comment: no, but you can propagate an existing login session if the account is enabled for delegation.

Comment: hi,  i think you can use Windows Authentification SSO look at this on google or on some blog they are some sample on web : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2014962b-0c47-43fd-8b9e-1ea9a987f555/wpf-windows-authentication-against-active-directory

Comment: you want SingleSingOn. you could obtain username - yes, password - no. how to validate username & password in ActiveDirectory -- https://github.com/KohrAhr/XTask/blob/master/Wpf.MainApp/Forms/LoginWindow.xaml

Comment: better way for SSO -- get current username and validate that user still belong to some role. as was suggested by @pascalsanchez

Comment: when the WPF process already runs in the context of the user that needs access to that "server in the LAN", why does it ask for reauthentication? this should work without any additional authentication. tell us more about your setup, what are you trying to access on that server? a http resource? a file on a file share?